# Error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help.
I write this query

```
SELECT SUM(fi.etiliquido) FROM fi WHERE fi.fno IN (
    SELECT * from divideString(
        SELECT TOP 1 REPLACE(CAST( u.nrdoc AS nvarchar),'/',',') FROM u_ups1 as u WHERE 1057 IN ( 
            SELECT * FROM divideString(REPLACE(CAST(u.nrdoc AS nvarchar),'/',','))
        )
    )
)
```

but sql server return this error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'SELECT'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near
>   ')'.

and I don't know why.
Can you help me?

UPDATE 
divideString is a function get a string and returns the numbers in that string

```
CREATE FUNCTION divideString (@InStr VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @TempTab TABLE
   (id int not null)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @InStr = REPLACE(@InStr + ',', ',,', ',')
    DECLARE @SP INT
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)
WHILE PATINDEX('%,%', @INSTR ) <> 0 
BEGIN
   SELECT  @SP = PATINDEX('%,%',@INSTR)
   SELECT  @VALUE = LEFT(@INSTR , @SP - 1)
   SELECT  @INSTR = STUFF(@INSTR, 1, @SP, '')
   INSERT INTO @TempTab(id) VALUES (@VALUE)
END
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: What is `divideString`?

Comment: What's `divideString`? Also, you should not do a `SELECT *` with `IN`, but only select one single field.

Comment: You can't have a select as argument to a function.

Comment: I am not sure if what's your function return. if it is return a table try change the line 4 to:  SELECT * FROM (divideString(REPLACE(CAST(u.nrdoc AS nvarchar),'/',','))) as d

Comment: I put the function in my question

Comment: Is fi the whole name of the table or is it an alias (in that case you forgot to write down the entire name)

Comment: fi is the name the table

Answer (score 1):

You need parentheses around subqueries (except for `in` subqueries), so:

```
SELECT SUM(fi.etiliquido)
FROM fi
WHERE fi.fno IN (SELECT d.val
                 FROM divideString( (SELECT TOP 1 REPLACE(CAST( u.nrdoc AS nvarchar(max)), '/', ',')
                                     FROM u_ups1 as u
                                     WHERE 1057 IN (SELECT d.val
                                                    FROM divideString(REPLACE(CAST(u.nrdoc AS nvarchar(max)), '/', ',') d(val)
                                                   )
                                    )
                                   ) d(val)
                );
```

Also, using `TOP` with no `ORDER BY` is usually suspicious.

Storing multiple values in a single column is not recommended.  However, I don't think you need a table-valued functions for this.  `LIKE` should work:

```
SELECT SUM(fi.etiliquido)
FROM fi
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM (SELECT TOP 1 u.nrdoc 
                    FROM u_ups1 u
                    WHERE '/' + u.nrdoc + '/' LIKE '%/1057/%' 
                   ) u
              WHERE '/' + u.nrdoc + '/' LIKE '%/' + fi.fno + '/%'
             );
```

And what you might want:

And, the logic that you want might be as simple as this:

```
SELECT SUM(fi.etiliquido)
FROM fi
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM u_ups1 u
              WHERE '/' + u.nrdoc + '/' LIKE '%/1057/%' AND 
                    '/' + u.nrdoc + '/' LIKE '%/' + fi.fno + '/%'
             );
```

Comment: @jcunham . . . Having `SELECT *` return exactly one unnamed column seems sloppy.